# Is there a better error reporting via e-mail for Django?

Tags: python, django

Quite often the error reports coming via e-mail are less than useful in tracking bugs. Most often this is due to missing session data and username of the user triggering the error. Is there a project or a library I could use to get more complete error reports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your own [exception middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#exception-middleware), as suggested [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/) (bottom of page).

There is a base snippets [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/638/) and an example of how to extract the traceback [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/420/)